# Why import duplicates from a module

Tags: python, tkinter, module, pygame

I am learning tkinter and noticed that people import multiple things sometimes.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

I was wondering why people do this for many modules, not just tkinter. I always thought that `import *` meant that you were importing everything from a module. So why do people import more items?

Comment: Why people do things they should not, is an eternal and unanswerable question.

Comment: Importing **everything** is a bad sign. Says that "*importer*" doesn't know what they're doing (in most of the cases).

Answer (score 1):

`tkinter.ttk` is a submodule of `tkinter`. Submodules aren't guaranteed to be loaded by `import *`; if you want them, it's safest to import them yourself. (Whether submodules are loaded by `import *` depends on the presence and contents of an `__all__` list, as well as what imports `__init__.py` performs and what imports have already been performed.)